# Tab no despliega el contenido

Tags: html, css

estoy teniendo problemas con este snippet https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/K0ZmK, ya que en mi pagina al clickear timeline no se despliega el tab, sigue en el about.

Asi es como lo tengo en mi codigo, pero la verdad deberia estar igual ya que lo copie y pegue de snippet

```
    <div class="container emp-profile">
    <form method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="profile-img">
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS52y5aInsxSm31CvHOFHWujqUx_wWTS9iM6s7BAm21oEN_RiGoog" alt=""/>
                    <div class="file btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                        Change Photo
                        <input type="file" name="file"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="profile-head">
                            <h5>
                                Kshiti Ghelani
                            </h5>
                            <h6>
                                Web Developer and Designer
                            </h6>
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Timeline</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="submit" class="profile-edit-btn" name="btnAddMore" value="Edit Profile"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="profile-work">
                    <p>WORK LINK</p>
                    <a href="">Website Link</a><br/>
                    <a href="">Bootsnipp Profile</a><br/>
                    <a href="">Bootply Profile</a>
                    <p>SKILLS</p>
                    <a href="">Web Designer</a><br/>
                    <a href="">Web Developer</a><br/>
                    <a href="">WordPress</a><br/>
                    <a href="">WooCommerce</a><br/>
                    <a href="">PHP, .Net</a><br/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="tab-content profile-tab" id="myTabContent">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Username</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>Kshiti123</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Nombre</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>Kshiti Ghelani</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Apellido</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>Kshiti Ghelani</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Email</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>kshitighelani@gmail.com</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Phone</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>123 456 7890</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Profession</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>Web Developer and Designer</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Experience</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>Expert</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Hourly Rate</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>10$/hr</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Total Projects</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>230</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>English Level</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>Expert</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Availability</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>6 months</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label>Your Bio</label><br/>
                                <p>Your detail description</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>           
</div>
```

Se les ocurre como puedo hacer para que el tab timeline funcione? Estuve revisandolo un tiempo, pero la verdad estoy bastante perdido. La publicacion me sigue pidiendo que escriba ya que es muy largo el codigo, asi que espero tengan un buen dia (?

Comment: ¿que version de bootstrap estas usando?  Si es la 5 entonces debes cambiar todos los atributos `data-` por `data-bs`

Comment: Es la version 4.1

Comment: Pues va a ser que te falta agregar el jquery seguramente. El codigo de los tabs esta bien y deberia funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asegurate de tener los javascript en la página

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Puedes verlo funcionando en [esta página](https://creatuweb.espaciolatino.com/sols/tabs.html#nav-contact). mira el código fuente y al final, antes del body tienes los links a los scripts js.